# Foreign Keys and importing data in MySQL workbench issues

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have looked everywhere and seen most of the threads pertaining to this issue but still can't get it to work for me.

This is what I made using Workbench. It's a real estate database:

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS projet3;
CREATE DATABASE projet3;
USE projet3;

CREATE TABLE Localite (
Localite_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Commune VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Departement SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Localite_ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Bien (
Bien_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
SurCar1 DOUBLE NOT NULL,
TypeLoc VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
NoPP SMALLINT NOT NULL,
Localite_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (Bien_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Localite FOREIGN KEY (localite_ID) REFERENCES localite (Localite_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE Mutation (
Mutation_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
DateMutation DATETIME NOT NULL,
ValeurFonciere INT NOT NULL,
Bien_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (Mutation_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Bien FOREIGN KEY (Bien_ID) REFERENCES bien (Bien_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Adresse;
CREATE TABLE Adresse (
Adresse_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NoVoie SMALLINT NOT NULL,
TypeVoie VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
NomVoie VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
CodePostal INT NOT NULL,
Bien_ID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
PRIMARY KEY (Adresse_ID),
CONSTRAINT FK_Bien FOREIGN KEY (Bien_ID) REFERENCES bien (Bien_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;`
```

The corresponding model looks like this:
[EER model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMCVZ.jpg)
I had to change the relationship between Bien and Adresse to a 1 on 1, which I then forward engineered. I understand I could integrate the Adresse attributes into the Bien table but for the sake of the tasks I have to perform on it I have kept them separate.

However, when I then try to import data into any table with a foreign key the workbench refuses giving me this:
[Cannot add or update child row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM7uN.jpg)

I have also tried to simply create the tables, import the data and then create the foreign keys but I get the same result.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You problem is

that you  have twice

```
CONSTRAINT FK_Bien FOREIGN KEY (Bien_ID) REFERENCES bien (Bien_ID) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

As every Foreign key needs his **unique name**.

So **rename** the second in the table `Adresse` for example to `FK_Bien1`

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that as soon as I tried to run the code.

Comment: Super Accept the answer it it helped

Comment: It didn't solve the problem of not being able to import data and the error it gave me.

Comment: please add to the fiddle what ypou try to do. of course3 before you a a row with a foreign key you have to fill up all related tables first or add a NULL

Answer (score 0):

**Temporarily disable the foreign key checks** after creating the tables & before loading the data by using the following command:

```
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0
```

Once you load/import the data into the tables, you can enable the foreign key checks by setting it back to 1. Some of the use case of this parameter have been well documented on [TablePlus's blog](https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/08/mysql-how-to-temporarily-disable-foreign-key-constraints.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it didn't work. I tried it twice, First time I ran the 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;' before I imported data successfully into the localite but then it still gave the error when trying to import into bien. The second time I ran the code before importing into localite and again before importing into bien, and I got the error message again.